# How to start an X display on vt via ssh?

Tags: linux, xorg

I would like to remotely startup the X server on a vt (i.e. vt1) through ssh connection.

---

The scenario is scratched as following:

```
|Host Machine| ---ssh---> |Target Machine| ==HDMI== |Display Screen|
```

The target machine is directly connected to a display screen (via HDMI, DP, VGA, etc.).

---

In other words, I would like to:

1. There's a default X server started with A user (controlled via systemd)
2. ssh to target machine
3. (Optional) Change to B user's X on another vt
4. The target machine's display screen shows up the desktop without login
5. Any graphics apps are runnable with `DISPLAY=:0 glxgears` (taking glxgears as example, :0 as an example)
6. The app shows up on the target machine's display screen (showing up is optional since it default shows the vt1), but not here on the host

Note:

- ssh X11forward is not acceptable
- Auto-login is not acceptable (since auto-login can only specify one user, and not switchable without a reboot)

Comment: VNCs are just alike X11forward which is not acceptable. I need to make sure that the application is run with full speed (though no need to see it).

Comment: You run the vncserver restricted to `localhost` and port-forward the display without enabling x11forwarding. Your other option is the insecure XDMCP. Other than that, x11forwading is about it.

Comment: Can VNC servers run without an already logged in X? In addition, I consider it hard to switch X users with VNC servers.

Comment: Yes, you source your `~/.xinitrc` in your `~/.vnc/xstartup` to behave if you had just logged into a terminal without any X session running and typed `startx`. systemd can handles user-mode vnc sessions. Arch has a decent wiki [TigerVNC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC)

Comment: Please help me to migrate to Super User or Unix & Linux.

Comment: I just flagged for moderator intervention to help with the move.